# I want to find the difference between 2 tables and the output should be in the expected format

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find the difference between 2 tables and the output should be in the expected format

Table AAA(NUM,TXT)

```
1   One
2   too
3   Three
4   Four
```

Table BBB(NUM,TXT)

```
1   One
3   
4   Four
2   Two
5   Five
```

I am using the below query in oracle to get the differences

```
select 'only A' where_, only_a.* from (select num, txt from AAA minus select num, txt from BBB) only_a union all
select 'only B' where_, only_b.* from (select num, txt from BBB minus select num, txt from AAA) only_b
```

OUTPUT is

[image]

What I want or Expected Output is

[image]

I want best query to get the output in desired format as shown in this question about

Comment: Add an `order by` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  aaa (num, txt) as
  3    (select 1, 'One'   from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'too'   from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'Three' from dual union all
  6     select 4, 'Four'  from dual
  7    ),
  8  bbb (num, txt) as
  9    (select 1, 'One'  from dual union all
 10     select 2, 'Two'  from dual union all
 11     select 3, null   from dual union all
 12     select 4, 'Four' from dual union all
 13     select 5, 'Five' from dual
 14    )
```

Query:

```
 15  select 'only A' what, a.* from aaa a minus select 'only A', b.* from bbb b
 16  union all
 17  select 'only B' what, b.* from bbb b minus select 'only B', a.* from aaa a
 18  order by 2, 1;

WHAT          NUM TXT
------ ---------- -----
only A          2 too
only B          2 Two
only A          3 Three
only B          3
only B          5 Five

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a single `FULL OUTER JOIN` (rather than your query which `SELECT`s from the tables 4 times and uses 2 `MINUS`es and a `UNION ALL`):

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN a.num IS NOT NULL
       THEN 'only A'
       ELSE 'only B'
       END AS what,
       COALESCE(a.num, b.num) AS num,
       CASE
       WHEN a.num IS NOT NULL
       THEN a.txt
       ELSE b.txt
       END AS txt
FROM   aaa a
       FULL OUTER JOIN bbb b 
       ON a.num = b.num AND a.txt = b.txt
WHERE  a.num IS NULL
OR     b.num IS NULL
ORDER BY num, what
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE AAA(NUM,TXT) AS
SELECT 1,   'One'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   'too'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,   'Three' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,   'Four'  FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE BBB(NUM,TXT) AS
SELECT 1,   'One'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,   NULL   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,   'Four' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   'Two'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,   'Five' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| WHAT | NUM | TXT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| only A | 2 | too |
| only B | 2 | Two |
| only A | 3 | Three |
| only B | 3 | *null* |
| only B | 5 | Five |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/t45Y79Cs)